# Testing React Apps with Phantom/Casper

Tags: testing, reactjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm diving into functional testing and attempting to get a few simple tasks working. The app is built in ReactJS and I've decided to use Phantom/Casper. The problem is that even the most basic tasks fail.

In short, is there a trick for testing React apps with Phantom/Casper?

I've installed Phantom (v.2.1.1) and Casper (v1.1.0-beta5). As a first attempt I created a simple script to capture an image:

**capture.js**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
  },
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start('http://localhost:9494', function() {
  console.log("page loaded");
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('img.png');
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Then run the script:

```
> casperjs capture.js
```

Viewing `localhost:9494` in my browser pulls up the app as it should. But the resulting `capture()` image is a blank screen.

I've also tried adding a `wait()`, `waitForSelector()` and `waitForResource()` to no avail.

Here's the output in the console:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://localhost:9494/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://localhost:9494/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://localhost:9494/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://localhost:9494/ (HTTP 200) page loaded
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /path/to/img.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /path/to/img.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 848ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 848ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

Comment: running into same problem. A normal webpage would be fine, just react app doesn't load

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the babel-polyfill NPM package to your project (or any other version of the polyfill) and then in your main index.js(x) entry point for your app, include this line at the top:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

We were having the exact same issue you are experiencing and this fixed it for us.
We had tried injecting the babel polyfill as part of the Casper test suite, but it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you did the waiting. Make sure your capture is in the wait callback. I usually use code like this and it often happens that you need to adjust the waiting time to see results.

3 seconds is usually enough to crawl public websites, that's how I use it.

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(3000, function() {
        this.capture('foo.jpg', undefined, 
            {
                format: 'jpg',
                quality: 75
            });
    });
});
```