# How to trigger onChange with casperjs and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, casperjs

So, it appears that by calling `$('#input').val('email@example').change()`, it doesn't trigger the React input `onChange` event.

But this is really necessary for using something like *CasperJS* for integration testing (filling out a form and submitting, etc.).

So how to do this? I haven't been able to find a solution online or by trying various things in the browser and looking at the React Devtools value of the state.

Here are some related links, that aren't particularly helpful.
[Why jQuery.val( value ) does not dispatch any event from the DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961469/why-jquery-val-value-does-not-dispatch-any-event-from-the-dom-element/3961475#3961475)

Comment: This may be duplicate to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353482/testing-react-apps-with-phantom-casper).

Comment: The question that needs to be answered is _Can CasperJS and PhantomJS find React components inside React visual dom?_ Or is there a test framework that is more suitable for React apps?

Comment: The screenshots work totally fine. But the jQuery of `$('input').val('something').change()` does *not* trigger React's `onChange` event. Workaround is to not use state for text input values.

Comment: Another reason to use Redux to keep state for text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

So, to enable the testing, I changed the input from being controlled to being a normal HTML input. For the `onSubmit` function, I use a `ref` to find the input value. Couldn't find a way to trigger `onChange` programmatically.